# Draw polygonial elements and make them clickable

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to make a phone panel with clickable buttons. (HTML5, no need to support old browsers)
For example. the best mobile phone that ever was:

[image: An N95 Front Panel]

The buttons for this phone should be clickable and have a `Javascript` function assigned to.
Let's suppose that the input is the panelImage and an array of buttons, each button containing an array of vertices (x,y for each)

```
{
    "panelImage": [],
    "buttons": [
        {
            "action": "Menu",
            "vertices": [ {"x": 3, "y": 2}, {"x": 3, "y": 7}, {"x":6, "y":7}, {"x": 6, "y":2} ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What's the best way to implement this?
The only way I know how is to draw this on a canvas and then, using some mathematical algorithm, figure out which button was clicked.
If there is a better way, one that will identify `click` using browser events, I would prefer that.

This should work on modern browsers (IE9+)

Comment: If you want to avoid using the canvas element, there's always <map> - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/fLyrz/

**Canvas provides a useful method to detect if an [x,y] is inside a path (your polygon is a path).**

```
context.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY);
```

**So button#1 in your image can be defined in an object like this:**

```
var buttons=[];

buttons.push({
    id:1,
    points:[{x:24,y:270},{x:57,y:272},{x:57,y:289},{x:24,y:285}
]});
```

You can get the path points from an image app (eg. MS Paint, etc).

**Then you can listen for mousedown and test if button#1 was pressed:**

```
function handleMouseDown(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
      if(mouseIsInButton(buttons[i],mouseX,mouseY)){
          alert("You pressed "+buttons[i].id);
      }
  }
}

function mouseIsInButton(button,x,y){
    var points=button.points;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(points[0].x,points[0].y);
    for(var i=1;i<points.length;i++){
        var pt=points[i];
        ctx.lineTo(pt.x,pt.y);
    }
    ctx.closePath();
    return(ctx.isPointInPath(x,y));
}
```

**Note:** `context.isPointInPath` tests only the last drawn path.  That's why the mouseIsInButton function redraws the path for button#1 before testing if it was hit using context.isPointInPath.

Comment: Great answer with a simple example. Thanks